What happens when two laws contradict each other?
A recent example of this is the DOJ's lawsuit against SpaceX for discriminating against asylum seekers, and the ITAR laws that prevent them from hiring asylum seekers (because they make missile technology and can therefore only hire US Citizens with security clearance). In this case, two federal laws conflict.
Another situation I am familiar with was a case where an employee on an  H1B visa at a company I worked for had his visa expire after six years, and although the management made it clear that that meant he could not work there, he continued to hang out and do a few things. He then sued under the Illinois wage laws that meant the company was obliged to pay him for his time, even though it was illegal for them to hire him without a valid work visa. In this particular case the federal law was ignored and the state law took precedence.
Irrespective of those two cases (I'm sure a lot depends on the details), what are the general principles where laws conflict either from different jurisdictions or, as surely happens, within the same jurisdiction? I understand that "the court decides" but how does the court decide?
I'm in the USA, but also interested in what happens beyond my borders.

Related: Law.SE: contradictory laws

In the second case it seems clear that 1) company MUST pay worker; 2) company can be punished for illegally employing worker, if that's a breach of a law (and I assume it is), 3) worker can be punished for illegally working in the country, if that's a breach of a law (and I assume it is)

@SwissFrank in the second case the employee violated visa conditions, but that's not a crime. Employing someone without proper authorization is.

The DOJ lawsuit is not about asylum seekers, it is about people who have been granted asylum or were admitted as refugees. As such there is no conflict. If there were a conflict, then the more specific federal law would control according to 8 USC §1324b(a)(2)(C). This section of law is the reason why it's legal to hire only US citizens for jobs that require a security clearance. Note that ITAR is not security clearance.

Those are not good examples
In the first case, the DoJ’s position is that there is no such law that prevents SpaceX from hiring asylum seekers. In the second, the two laws don’t conflict: the Federal law says the company can’t legally employ this person, the state law says employees get paid and doesn’t care if they were hired legally or not.
However, it is a good question
First, courts take the position that the legislature (or executive) does not want to promulgate ineffective laws. So, the starting point for the analysis is to find a way of reading the law so that any conflict is eliminated or, at least, minimised. Such a reading can almost always be found.
In the small number of cases where a conflict remains, there are several hierarchies involved.

Federal law beats state law providing the Federal government remains within the scope of its powers. Similarly, state law beats local government law. Government law beats private law (e.g. if a rule of a company or HOA breaches the law, it’s invalid).
Constitutional law beats statute law. Primary statutes (Acts) beat secondary statutes (Regulations or Orders). Statute law beats case law.
Newer law beats older law
More specific beats less specific - a particular law about motorcycles will be preferred over a general rule about motor vehicles, for example.


Do you know how this works when laws between countries conflict? e.g. X is legal in country A, but illegal in country B. There have been some interesting extraterritorial jurisdiction cases recently.

@Justas: See Law.SE: How do extraditions work between countries with different law contexts?

When higher-ranked decisions overrule previous lower ones, is it required to signal which laws are deprecated, or do they just stay in the books until they come up again? i.e. with (US) constitutional amendments, I've heard (?) they have to explicitly mention which portion they are amending, but I imagine that it would be a burden for higher courts to list every single jurisdiction's related laws.

@shea: "Decisions" in your comment is not a standard term. Court decisions generally do not "deprecate" laws, but they can rule them unconstitutional. Often this will not make the entire law unconstitutional, just the application of that law in the specific case at hand and similar cases. It's not for the courts to figure out what to do with the law afterwards, but the government may decide on a rewording.

I'm not sure I understand the need of the first part about finding readings to eliminate or minimise conflicts. It seems that the bullet list provided is sufficient; the "newer law beats older law" by itself basically eliminates any conflict: just do what the newer law dictates.

@gnarrithas sometimes a law contradicts itself.  If there is an interpretation of the law where the self contradiction doesn't exist, that interpretation will be favored.


A recent example of this is the DOJ's lawsuit against SpaceX for discriminating against asylum seekers, and the ITAR laws that prevent them from hiring asylum seekers (because the make missile technology and can therefore only hire US Citizens with security clearance). In this case two federal laws conflict.

According to the DOJ, ITAR laws do not impose any such restriction. See the press release Justice Department Sues SpaceX for Discriminating Against Asylees and Refugees in Hiring:

Export control laws impose no such hiring restrictions. Moreover, asylees’ and refugees’ permission to live and work in the United States does not expire, and they stand on equal footing with U.S. citizens and lawful permanent residents under export control laws. Under these laws, companies like SpaceX can hire asylees and refugees for the same positions they would hire U.S. citizens and lawful permanent residents. And once hired, asylees and refugees can access export-controlled information and materials without additional government approval, just like U.S. citizens and lawful permanent residents.

The court will have to determine whether this is in fact the correct interpretation, but to the best of my knowledge it is.

an H1B at a company I worked for had his visa expire after six years, and although the management made it clear that that meant he could not work there, he continued to hang out and do a few things. He then sued under the Illinois wage laws that meant the company was obliged to pay him for his time, even though it was illegal for them to hire him without a valid work visa. In this particular case the federal law was ignored and the state law took precedence.

I cannot find the actual case based on your description, so I'm responding to how you described this case. The Federal law was not ignored. It was  in fact illegal for the firm to continue employing the individual and they were in violation of the Federal law. The lawsuit however was not about whether they had to continue the employment, but whether they had to pay for the work done. Regardless of whether the employee was hired legally or not, the wages for the work performed have to be paid. There's no conflict. The Federal law violation doesn't excuse the State law violation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A pretty common rule internationally is lex specialis. When two laws conflict, but one is a general law and the other is specific to the case, then the second law is taken as an exception to the first law. For instance, laws about contracts can contradict laws about employment contracts, but the latter are more specific.
In this case, "You cannot discriminate when hiring" is the general rule, and "You must discriminate (on security clearance) when hiring for ITAR positions" is (or would be) the more specific rule.

Correct. I've worked in similar environments. By law you can't discriminate when hiring, but to meet legal security requirements we weren't allowed to hire people with certain nationalities or even people who'd visited certain countries within the previous 7 years. Which meant we had to reject a decent number of otherwise qualified candidates for hard to fill positions.
